# Are my move constructor and move assignment operator written well?

Tags: c++, constructor, operators, c++17, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am adding move constructor and move assignment operator in this struct.
Can someone tell me if they are written good?
When I run the code without these two methods it is going ok, but when I add these two it is not working.
Thanks a lot

```
    struct Data {
        Data() = default;
    
        Data(const unsigned int _x) : data(new unsigned char[_x]), size(_x) {}
    
        Data(const Data &_d) : data(new unsigned char[_d.size]), size(_d.size) {
            memcpy(data, _d.data, _d.size);
        }
    
        ~Data() {
            delete[] data;
            size = 0;
        };
    
        Data& operator=(const Data &_d) {
            if (this == &_d) {
                return *this;
            }
            unsigned char *tmp(new unsigned char[_d.size]);
            memcpy(tmp, _d.data, _d.size);
            delete[] data;
            data = tmp;
            size = _d.size;
            return *this;
        }
```

Here is my move constructor should I first delete data and if the sizes are not equal allocate data with new size?

```
Data(Data &&_d)
    {
        data = _d.data;
        _d.data = nullptr;
        size = _d.size;
        _d.size = 0;
    }
```

And here is my move assignment operator

```
    Data& operator=(Data&& _d)
    {
        if (this != &_d)
        {
            delete[] data;
            data = _d.data;
            _d.data = nullptr;
            size = _d.size;
            _d.size = 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    
        unsigned char *data = nullptr;
        unsigned int size = 0;
    };
```

Comment: You should almost never write your own copy and move constructors (see "the rule of zero"). Use standard containers and smart pointers instead. The only exception is implementing your own smart-pointer-like classes.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. thanks for the advice. this is what I was asked to do, I got the code and needed to add these two methods

Comment: you can delegate the def ctor to do the work of the move ctor then make a swapping

Comment: @asmmo could you show me how to do it, please? I dont know how would that look like

Comment: _"... but when I add these two it is not working."_  Is **working** relevant for it to be considered "written good"?

Comment: @Eljay of course not. But I am supposed to add just these two methods in this already written code and it should work so we can use it in other class as datatype

Comment: In what way is the code _not working_ when you add the two methods?  Does it not compile?  Is the compiler emitting warnings?  How are you testing it, such that it is not working?

Comment: I have Data d1(500); Data d2 = move(d1); and when I print the size for both, i just get for d1 size=0; but without my method it prints for both size=500

Comment: Once you `std::move` an object, you can't look at it, because it is supposed to be left in a valid-but-unspecified state suitable for destruction or being assigned to.  Which is what your code does.  (The one part I'd remove is checking for self-assignment; instead make those kind of routines self-assignment safe rather than optimize for the pathological case, such as dewaffled's suggestion of `std::swap`.)

Comment: @Eljay but shouldn't my program print d2 properly? I understand that size=0 for d1 because I put it that way, but d2 size should be 500

Comment: It's printing 500 for me for `d2`.  You should add these new relevant informational updates to the original question rather than in comments, including your code.  It appears you have a bug somewhere in the code you have not provided.  Your provided code should be a [mcve].

Comment: @Eljay I understood what was the mistake. I was trying to print data that was moved. When I deleted that line, everything is ok. I have now other question, if I have in other class just Data d, I dont have pointer so my move ctor there wouldn't be the same as here?

Comment: Your new question should be posted as a separate new question, complete with [mcve] code.

Comment: @Eljay I edited this one, hope it is not a problem.. I will try to post the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.

But there is also a pattern to implement move assignments using [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap):

```
Data& operator=(Data&& _d)
{
    std::swap(data, _d.data);
    std::swap(s, _d.size);
    return *this;
}
```

Here the old data will be released when `_d` destructor is invoked.

This is not a "more correct way" but it is easier to write and leaves less space to forget to properly dispose the resources.

Move constructor can reuse move assignment:

```
Data(Data&& _d)
    : this() 
{
    *this = std::move(_d);
}
```

Again, this is not necessary a better way but reduces amount of duplicated code.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I will take a look. But we had lesson about move ctor and move assignment operator, so this is just an exercise to do it... but I am not sure if I did it right.

Answer (score 1):

You have provided begin and end methods in your class. Probably you want to work with STL. In this case you should add noexcept if you want to provide strong exception guarantee. STL containers won't use your move constructors/assignments if they are noexcept(false).

```
Data& operator=(Data&& _d) noexcept
{
    if (this != &_d)
    {
        delete[] data;
        data = _d.data;
        _d.data = nullptr;
        size = _d.size;
        _d.size = 0;
    }
    return *this;
}


Data(Data &&_d) noexcept
{
    data = _d.data;
    _d.data = nullptr;
    size = _d.size;
    _d.size = 0;
}
```

[Here you can read about it](http://www.hlsl.co.uk/blog/2017/12/1/c-noexcept-and-move-constructors-effect-on-performance-in-stl-containers#:%7E:text=Tagging%20our%20move%20constructor%20with,set%20on%20your%20move%20constructor.)

> An STL container can only use the move constructor in it's resizing
> operation if that constructor does not break its strong exception
> safety guarantee. In more plain language, it wont use the move
> constructor of an object if that can throw an exception. This is
> because if an exception is thrown in the move then the data that was
> being processed could be lost, where as in a copy constructor the
> original will not be changed.

Comment: thank you, but the exercise is to make move ctor and move assignment operator work properly so we can use the struct in other class. I need this to work properly

Comment: You have default constructor enabled, which doesn't allocate memory. It leads to the situation when you delete a nullptr, which is normal, but not a good coding style. Shouldn't default constructor be deleted?

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but as I said, we got the .cpp and .h files already done, just to add these two methods

Comment: You have begin() and end() methods implemented. Probably to use with STL, probably not only with algorithms but with containers as well. That is why noexcept should be considered.

Comment: This struct will be used in other BigData class that has Data type and prints with range-based for-loop the data